# Two Definitions of Barsotti-Tate Representations

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

In different articles I have seen different definitions of *Barsotti-Tate representations*. I am wondering if and how these definitions are equivalent.

In Section 1.1 of [Conrad-Diamond-Taylor](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1999-12-02/S0894-0347-99-00287-8/S0894-0347-99-00287-8.pdf) they say that, for $K/\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ a finite extension and $E\subset \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\ell$ some coefficient field and $V$ a 2-dimensional vector space over $E$, a Galois representation
$$
\rho: G_K \to GL(V)
$$
is Barsotti-Tate if there exists an $\ell$-divisible group $\Gamma_{/\mathcal{O}_K}$ such that $\rho$ acting on a stable $\mathcal{O}_E$-lattice inside $V$ is isomorphic as a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell[G_K]$-module to the generic fibre of $\Gamma_{/\mathcal{O}_K}$ with its action by $G_K.$ (This definition explains the name.)

In Section 2.3.1 of [Gee-Liu-Savitt](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~tsg/Index_files/shape.pdf) they say that the representation $\rho$ as above is Barsotti-Tate if for all embeddings $\tau:K\to \overline{K}$ we have that the $\tau$-labelled Hodge-Tate weights are $HT_\tau(V)=\{0,1\}.$

It is not obvious to me that these definitions are equivalent. Is this easy to see? Is a reference for this fact available?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it more or less Théorème 1.4 from Breuil's paper GROUPES p - DIVISIBLES, GROUPES FINIS ET MODULES FILTRES (Annals of Math. 151, 2000, 489-549. ? (here is a link from Breuil's webpage : https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~breuil/PUBLICATIONS/p-divisibles.pdf )

Comment: Ah, great! I didn't know about this reference before, but it seems to do the trick. I'd still be interested to hear from someone if there is an intuitive reason why one would expect this to be true. Also, is this result known for p=2 or are there some problems in that case?

Comment: For $p=2$ the theorem is proved in a paper of Kisin.